# ASMX webservice, Windows store device client, SOAP Auth Header

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, asmx

I want to consume an ASMX web service with SOAP Authentication Header(Username, Password) in a Windows Store project. When I add it as a Service reference MessageHeader part from each method are missing.

My ASMX service requires Basic SOAP Header authentication from every method that is accessed by client. But proxy generated by Windows store project in VS2013 has not generated method to include SOAP header with the request.

My ASMX Method in Browser:

```
POST /Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://WebReference:9010/GetNewSystemno"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<AuthHeader xmlns="http://WebReference:9010/">
  <Username>string</Username>
  <Password>string</Password>
</AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<GetNewSystemno xmlns="http://WebReference:9010/" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetNewSystemnoResponse xmlns="http://WebReference:9010/">
  <GetNewSystemnoResult>string</GetNewSystemnoResult>
</GetNewSystemnoResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2012/10/21/adding-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf.aspx   this link helped me to inject custom soap header as needed into the outgoing request... posting for future reference to anyone!!!